# Please delete my Electrical Engineering Account

Tags: support

I would like to delete my account for Electrical Engineering S.E but I do not know how. I could not find the the delete button. Is there a procedure I need to follow. I googled it showed to delete my stack exchange account which I would like to keep. I just wan't to get rid the Electrical Engineering account. I believe this question may be a duplicate. Planning to use reverse engineering to get my answer as linked and related question would immediately pop up and save up my search time. IF none found please guide me and for the down voters  go ahead down vote this question as I'm going to delete this profile anyway.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: Why do you need to delete your account?  You could simply ignore it with the same affect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mods don't delete accounts *on request* for various reasons (which are probably on meta.stackexchange.com somewhere). Follow the directions on [this help center page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) to request your account to be deleted.

Comment: `"Mods don't delete accounts on request"` and `"Follow the directions on this help center page to request your account to be deleted."` For those of us who didn't get it on the first read (like me): It's not the moderators removing the accounts, it's the main SE team. As far as I'm aware, moderators can (temporarily) suspend users but not delete them.

Comment: @Mast There's a "User requested account deletion" procedure that gets followed to help make sure anyone is being sarcastic or is not really serious about it (among other reasons). Moderators can delete users but that is reserved for spam or vandalism accounts.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.